# Debugging ASP.NET 4.0 site in VS 2010 with URL Rewrite enabled

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

is this something basic or am I missing something?

My ASP.NET (4.0) site has a web.config with URL rewrite rules. When I run it in debug mode (local webserver) all the URLs fail because the local web server does not recognize the rules (e.g. I have /register which maps to register.aspx etc.)

Is there someway I can get the debug system to recognize my URL rewrite rules? Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 3):

The best bet seems to be to move to [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) if you can, since that can use the same URL Rewriting module as "real" IIS, and should also have fewer other bug-causing differences than Cassini has.

An alternative would be to do your rewriting with [UrlRewritingNet](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) if that'll handle the rules that you need. That's a .NET HttpModule, so it'll work on either Cassini or IIS.

Comment: IIS Express doesn't seem to be out yet? I did install Webmatrix but apparently IIS exp. isn't integrated to VS 2010 yet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the URL Rewriting Module installed in your IIS. (I assume you mean IIS with local webserver. Cassini won't work)

Its definetly possible to debug a webapplication running on local IIS that uses URL Rewriting